# Website giving me 500 internal server error - is it .htaccess error?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My website is giving a 500 internal server error when I click on any category header menu, but the homepage is loading fine. I did some troubleshooting, but from my understanding it narrows down to .htaccess rewrite rules.

Here is my .htaccess code, I need help with this please:
My .htaccess code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with these rewrite rules?

Comment: This sounds to me more of  a syntax error than anything related to .htaccess. Check log files for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your `.htaccess` file with this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Troubleshooting 500 internal server error

1. Go **FTP** into your website
2. Open the file named **wp-config.php**
3. Find the line where you see `define('WP_DEBUG', false);`
4. Change **false** to **true** and save the file

Now you check..